# problemas com o res.send

Tags: node.js

Estou estudando node pra fazer uma api, e estou com problema na hora de enviar um res.send() com um array de objetos dentro, ele nao reconhece as propriedades

```
res.send({
      nextUrl,
      previousUrl,
      limit,
      offset,
      total,
  
      results: news.map((item) => ({
        id: item._id,
        title: item.title,
        text: item.text,
        banner: item.banner,
        likes: item.likes,
        comments: item.comments,
        name: item.user.name,
        username: item.user.username,
        userAvatar: item.user.avatar,
      })),
    });
```

acontece esse erro:

```
{
  "message": "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')"
}
```

meu git: https://github.com/Julia-Dev-sys/api-breakingnews

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O erro que você está recebendo pode estar relacionado com o objeto "user" que está dentro do objeto "item". Pelo erro, parece que o nome da propriedade "name" não está sendo encontrada dentro do objeto "user".

Uma possível solução seria adicionar uma verificação para garantir que a propriedade "user" exista antes de tentar acessar suas propriedades. Você pode tentar alterar a parte do código que cria o array de objetos para algo assim:

```
    results: news.map((item) => ({
    id: item._id,
    title: item.title,
    text: item.text,
    banner: item.banner,
    likes: item.likes,
    comments: item.comments,
    name: item.user ? item.user.name : '',
    username: item.user ? item.user.username : '',
    userAvatar: item.user ? item.user.avatar : '',
  })),
```

Dessa forma, o código verifica se o objeto "user" existe antes de tentar acessar suas propriedades. Se o objeto não existir, o valor da propriedade será definido como uma string vazia.

Comment: Ei!! obrigada! deu super certo